# PHP Twitch API slow

Tags: php

I'm using Twitch API to check if the user is online or offline. The code works great, but it slows the loading process of the site a lot. It can take everything from 5-10 seconds to load the site with it on. How may I reduce the loading time?

Shall I use cookies, sessions? Or how?

```
public function twitchOnline($twitchname){
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'.$twitchname
            ));

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $checkkey = "language" ;
            $position = strpos($response,$checkkey);

            curl_close($curl);  

            if ($position === false) {

            }else{
                if($twitchname != null){
                    echo "streamOnline";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just a guess. But you are trying to access a https url and have SSL deactivated. 'curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);' Try switching it on.

Comment: ssl is not deactivated. peer verification is. Which is a bad thing to do but it doesn't disable ssl...

Answer (score 0):

API calls like that are not meant to do on every page visit. You could use a cron on the server which checks the status of the streamer every 2 minutes, store the streamers status in a database and just retrieve that status from the database every page visit.

Comment: A cron is a process executing in the background. It does not get executed whenever a user visits a page. So no, the "first" page visit will not be slower. A cron gets executed at certain times. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Even with the CRON it takes forever to load?